# How can I resize my video & form section to align them side by side?

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, html5-video

I am trying to create a page similar to this:
https://www.figma.com/file/IholKo9XLAaBUqxmgC4Hl7/E-Carz?node-id=101%3A18722&mode=dev

I was able to align the first section correctly but in the second section I can't resize the video like how it looks in figma.
Whenever I try to reduce the height of the video it adds padding on left & right side of the video and if I try to remove the height attribute in my CSS code and just set width. It gives me a video with the original size which is too big.

Here's the CSS & HTML code for the video element.

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted src="./media/videos/production_id 4434242 (2160p).mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1074px" height="800px"></video>
</div>


.video-container
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

HTML & CSS for the form element:

```
<div class="form-section">
            <h3>
                Contact Us
            </h3>
            <h4>
                Our friendly team would love to hear from you.
            </h4>
            <form class="form-input">
                <div class="user-name">
                    <label for="first-name">
                        First Name
                    </label>
                    <input id="first-name" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                    <label for="last-name">
                        Last Name
                    </label>
                    <input id="last-name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Inlude a message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="input-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox">You agree to our friendly <a href="#">privacy policy</a>.</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Send Message</button>
            </form>
        </div>



.form-section
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 32px;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.form-input
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 24px;
    align-self: stretch;    
}

.user-name
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 32px;
    align-self: stretch;
}
```